# Using "recently" with the past simple tense

Tags: past-tense, adverbs, present-perfect

Is it fine to use ***recently*** with the past simple tense in the following sentence:

> ***Did you read*** any books recently?

Is it grammatically correct?

Or do I have to use:

> ***Have you read*** any books recently?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Using “recently” with past simple](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/76128/3281). Maybe we need to merge the questions together.